# telerik ASP.net MVC Grid Ajax binding problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, telerik-grid

I'm trying to use Telerik ASP.net MVC Grid, and find a problem.

When I use a grid in an ordinary View with Ajax binding, it works well. However, when I put the grid in a partial View that is loaded by an Ajax call, the grid's Ajax binding does not work then. From firebug, I find the ajax request for getting data did not send to server side.

I find a similar question in stackoverflow : [Telerik MVC: Loading Grid with ajax request don't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115749/telerik-mvc-loading-grid-with-ajax-request-dont-work) , but don't find solution.

Thank you!

Comment: it's working fine for me. can u show some code?

Answer (score 2):

I also have same problem and i find the solution basically it is due to telerik javascript file.

```
<%: Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar().DefaultGroup(group => group.Combined(true).Compress(true)) %>
```

copay and paste that code In master page before end of the body or if you are not using master page then place it on every page where u use ajax binding of telerik .

Answer (score 0):

the reason is I used `ClientEvents` as below:

```
Html.Telerik().Grid(Model)
.....
.Selectable()
.ClientEvents(e => e.OnRowSelected("onRowSelected"))
```

and I put the js code of  `onRowSelected` handler after the grid.

When I move the js code of `onRowSelected`  before the grid, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the OnSuccess event of the ajax call (in the AjaxOptions of the Ajax.ActionLink or Ajax.BeginForm)

```
OnSuccess = "function () {var html = $('#grid').html();$('#grid').html(html);}"
```

This force the ajax call for getting data.